# template_preprocess_HOOK: what do I put for HOOK?

Tags: theming

My objective: get and change the breadcrumb within a custom module.

So it's possible that template_preprocess_HOOK is not even the best tool to be using for this, please mention that.

My question, though, is what HOOK to use? Should it be called template_preprocess_mymodule or template_preprocess_mytheme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HOOK corresponds to the theme function or template you are preprocessing.

If you wanted to alter `page.tpl.php`, you would use `function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables)`.

If you wanted to alter `theme_item_list()`, you would use `function MYTHEME_preprocess_item_list(&$variables)`.

A note, any dashes should be converted to underscores.

So `views-view.tpl.php` would be altered by `function MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view(&$variables)`.

Comment: When I do that, I get WSOD. My function is called rescue_preprocess_views-view--testtaxo().

Comment: Check your PHP error log to find out what is causing the WSOD. It is possible you have a php syntax error within your preprocess function.

Comment: your function name can't have -'s in it: PHP is thinking you are trying subtraction :)

Comment: The question was about using 'template_preprocess_HOOK()'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your template file for breadcrumb menu is `my-breadcrumb.html.twig`.
So you can override variables in this template by defining `template_preprocess_my_breadcrumb(&$variables)` in a module.

Or you can also use
`MYTHEME_preprocess_my_breadcrumb(&$variables)`
in your `YOUTHEME.theme`